# Can we use the shape of an object that is instanced to particles with dynamic paint

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

So the general setup here is to use an animated particle emitter set as dynamic paint *brush*, which will cause deformations on another object set as dynamic paint *canvas*. The latter object has its surface type set to **Displace** under the heading *Dynamic Paint Advanced*.  Using this basic setup, when the particles make contact with the surface, the deformation in the canvas is a sphere shape which reflects a point with a radius.

Now when another object is instanced to replace the particles using the setting **Object** which is found in the particle settings' *Render* area, the particles now show up as the object that is attached here. However, the surface deformation that takes place on the brush canvas is still sphere-shaped.

So this brings me to the question, can we make the deformations that take place on the canvas reflect the shape of the object that is replacing the particles?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You could use rigid body simulation instead if you need dynamic brush objects.

Comment: It looks like there's [a lot of stuff](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3421/372) particle instances can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic Paint isn't necessary for this to be done.

Gleb Alexandrov recently posted a video showing how to use a cloth simulation to achieve damage on an object which matches the shape of the object that is colliding with it as shown here in his video Blender Tutorial: 9 Ways to Destroy Things  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJFE2pb0Ri4

Fist step: add a cloth simulation to the object that you want to have a worn-down damaged look.  To have the object become squashed without bouncing around or flattening out, just set 'Bending' to 0.0

[image]

Then you add a collision simulation to the object that will be causing the damage.  I used default settings for this.

[image]

Now use the Timeline to animate the damage-causing object to overlap with the cloth simulation object that is to receive the damage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **no**.

As an alternative, you could try using [rigid body simulation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aSergof/GSoC2012/Documentation).

Note that rigid body interactions will not work as expected currently, because rigid body simulation only takes into account the base mesh (no modifiers). However, some [recent improvements](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aSergof/GSoC2013/Documentation) will soon make this possible.