# Is there a way to make particles behave like rigid body objects?

Tags: physics, particles, rigid-body-simulation

I want to create a scene that has a lot of irregularly shaped objects piled up on the ground.  I don't want the objects to intersect with eachother.

I started off by creating a particle system that uses an object group containing these objects.  No matter what settings I 'messed with' I could not get the individual objects to behave the way I want them to - They would interact with the ground like perfect spheres, and they would pass through the other particle objects.

Is there a way to make particles have rigid body physics so they behave with each other and with the ground like real objects?

Or failing that - is there a way to copy rigid body attributes to many objects? (i.e. plan be - don't use a particle system, but rather make lots and lots of copies of the objects and just let them fall)

**Edit:**  I ended up applying the settings 26 times (there are 26 unique objects) and then copying those 26 objects several times. To produce this

[image: Alphabet]

but this was before there were any replies to this question. Thanks to WChargin's answer I will be able to copy the attibutes in one action next time I do something like this :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [Is] there a way to copy rigid body attributes to many objects?

**Copy Rigid Body Settings** sounds like it might do the trick. Select all the objects, then select the one with the correct settings last (make it the *active object*). Then, press <kbd>Space</kbd>> *Copy Rigid Body Settings*, or select *Copy from Others* from the Object Mode toolbox under *Rigid Body Tools.*

[image: Copying rigid body settings with the space-menu]

**EDIT:** You [can also use](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/is-there-a-way-to-make-particles-behave-like-rigid-body-objects/3422?noredirect=1#comment6024_3422) the *Copy to Selected* function of the right-click menu to copy *any* property from the active object to all selected objects; for example:

[image: Using "Copy to Selected" on the *Collision Shape* property]

---

To do it natively: if there is a way, I can't find it. I've tried *Particle Instance* modifier with rigid body instances, *Size Deflect* option, duplication, hooks… nada. Do post if you find a “cleaner” way to do it.

Comment: Maybe add a note about *Copy to selected* for copying specific settings?

Answer (score 11):

Do what you were doing and when the particle system has spawned enough objects stop the animation and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> which is **Make Duplicates Real**.

Now do what **WChargin** said in his [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3422/12).

Comment: Thank you.  Combined with what WChargin said this should be a good way to create a great many rigid body objects.  Useful to know.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeking for the same topic and I found a solution better than the "Make Duplicates Real".

The script/addon Copy Particles to Rigid Bodies does exactly what you want. Here you have the script and a test scene with easy instructions in it: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279329-Copy-Particles-to-Rigid-Bodies

Answer (score 0):

I noted if the tools 't' physics tab is visible You'll see Rigid Body Tools where a "Copy to Active" button exists.
If the Particles modifier has been applied to make the objects real.
I tried this RMB thing on a single value (which is not the goal) and it's grayed out because the selected objects do not have the Rigid Body Collisions applied yet. 
I don't think this has the right option 
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu
which is it?
And nor does CTRL-L the one with 'object data' didn't do it so I'm thinking it lacks a Link Physics choice there too.
So they both lack a copy physics attribute it seems.

This vid shows the Tools Physics TAB "Rigid Body Tools" sunsection "Object Tools" where "Copy from Active" hides.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y46GClyIOCM

*[rant: Still in the end there was more to do in my usecase = it didn't work really at all, so lack of real geo collision with Object or Group particle sims remains desired, but it will kill your computer with even a small armful of simple geometry, so it's really not possible to process lots of particles in this way it seems, and that explains why it's not integrated, but it's still needed in my mind. It just seems logistically out of reach to me eye at this time.]*

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If you have new question use [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button, provide link to this one if it's related to your question

Comment: It's an Answer. It seems the other ones did not help in my situation. It brings clarity. I think maybe there's an issue with the newer version or my particulars.