# How to make a Particles Mountain

Tags: particles

I have attached a file. In that a sphere is on the top and a plan at bottom and to the right there is group of particles. The group of particles are coming down from the face of the sphere and dropping on the plane. I want to make a mountain of the particles which i have the group. But my particles are not stay on the plane. I have added add passive (rigid body) to the plane so that particles stay on it but its not working. I want the particles to be stay on the plane and not die and make a mountain shape. May i know what other settings i have to make so that particles stay on the plane and make the mountain shape.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

To make particles collide on the plane, add Collision Physics to it and set the stickiness to 1. Perhaps also add some friction.

The particles will now stop on the plane, but they won't pile to a mountain as you want. That is because particles don't collide with each other. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/hard-self-collision-make-particles-occupy-space) for particle self collision.

Instead of particles, you may also try rigid body physics or water simulation (with enorm viscosity, don't know if that one will work though).

Comment: can u plz go little more in details or in animated way to get the clear result