# Blender particle system objects not colliding

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I have a simple particle System of falling balls but they won't collide to each other like in nature.
What am I doing wrong, what have I forgotten?
My aim is that the balls have volume and stack up like real putting them in a barrel o.s.l.t.

Thanks for any kind of help!

My current .blend of this http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/schneemann
[image: Screenshot of Blender UI with coloured balls]

Comment: Possible info: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/hard-self-collision-make-particles-occupy-space

Comment: Thanks, have read this allready. Even with molecular addon it won't work. I'm watching this molecular addon tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haS3B6q82kY for the 2nd time ... it won't work!

Answer (score 1):

Add the collision pannel under Physics, turn the Particle Friction up... hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but this has effect.Actually I think, there's someting wrong with my .blend. Some worldsettings or somting other.

Comment: typo: This has NO effect.

Comment: Ok, just trying to help...

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried out the "Molecular Addon" and head headaches for 2 days - but then it works!!!

Now I have particles which collide - to themselves and to other objects.
Blender rocks!

https://img3.picload.org/image/rodolppi/0154.png

Comment: Great! I like the image!