# How to drop particles so they land in a natural way?

Tags: particles

I have a plane as collision object and a house as particle generator. I'm dropping my particles. I have tweaked some settings so that they fall in some natural way, but they just bounce like a ball and disappear.

**Bouncing like a ball**
[image]

It should look as is they are thrown from the top and fall down in a natural way.

How can I achieve a result like the image below?

**Result i need few 20 particles (red house)**
[image]

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: To get nice collision boundaries, instead of using a particle system, you could duplicate the house 20 times and use rigid body physics.

Comment: @ajwood but particles system i can tweak setting from 20 to 35, random and many more, etc

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haS3B6q82kY Here is everything you need to know.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/is-there-a-way-to-make-particles-behave-like-rigid-body-objects

Comment: You should use keyed particles instead of a physics based system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8