# Is it possible to apply cloth simulation and collision on a character?

Tags: animation, armature, physics

I have a character that I created and built the armature for the character but I want it to make it so when the character touches his face, his face does something similar to the cloth simulation on this video on 4:20: [9 Ways to Destroy Things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJFE2pb0Ri4) but much subtler.I know there needs to be another object to have a collision setup but can one object have a collision and cloth simulation at the same time so when the character touches himself, his mesh has been affected.

Comment: I wonder if making a linked duplicate to use as a proxy would would with the self-interaction.  The proxy could be invisible and also maybe lower-poly but when it moves, it will do everything that the visible model does and this should give the illusion of self-interaction.  The invisible duplicate of the model could have an entirely different modifier/simulation setup from the rendered model.

Comment: This reminds me of a question that was never answered, I guess I should do that now.  That thing at t= 4m20s is exactly what I was hoping for when I asked this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/can-we-use-the-shape-of-an-object-that-is-instanced-to-particles-with-dynamic-pa

Comment: Also related is the following thread with different methods for wear and tear. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/procedurally-generating-wear-on-an-object/3425#3425